# Golang: get coordinate from .tif file

Tags: go, tiff

I downloaded the terrain data from the site (example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OiFy-vLq9CvVeqNg9VogmxSPOMcpcD1W/view?usp=sharing ) and got the data. Specifically interested in the format *_DCM.tif, which, as I understand it, stores data on point - longitude, latitude and altitude.

With gdal I can convert a file to .XYZ file and take the data, but the file size becomes too large.

[XYZ file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmz6c.png)

In this regard, 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to parse the tif file somehow and get this data?
2. Is it possible to convert programmatically .tif in .XYZ and work with the received data?

Which libraries have I already reviewed:

https://github.com/chai2010/tiff/tree/master/examples

https://github.com/lukeroth/gdal/blob/master/examples/tiff/tiff.go

https://github.com/airbusgeo/godal/blob/main/doc_test.go

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rwcarlsen/goexif/exif

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/evanoberholster/imagemeta

**UPDATE**:

I found the gdallocationinfo method. For example, I have converted all tiff files to VRT and am working with it: gdallocationinfo -xml -wgs84 dsm-mosaic.vrt 28.000139 50.999861

[gdallocationinfo result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukaKo.png)

I need "Value" - altitude

But I couldn't find an implementation on Golang in any way. I also tried to rewrite the code in Python, but without success.

I was told that calling a console command from code is a bad idea.

If anyone knows how to get information on latitude and longitude, then I will be gdal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tiff](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/image/tiff) package of the standard library can't handle the encoding used, it says that the SampleFormat that was uses is not supported: `tiff: unsupported feature: sample format`.

The [github.com/chai2010/tiff](https://github.com/chai2010/tiff) library does the job. The example below decodes the image so we can loop over all of its pixels. The desired format uses GPS coordinates, so we have to do some conversion work, I hardcoded the offsets to keep the example concise, parsing them dynamically from the file name should not be difficult.

I am not 100% sure about the `float64(x) / float64(bounds.Max.X))` part, since the values don't seem to match the screenshot you sent. Could be that some other scaling values should be used depending on the grid size, but I figure you can fix that yourself.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "image/color"
    "os"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/chai2010/tiff"
)

func main() {
    input, err := os.Open("N050E028_DSM.tif")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // TODO: parse the offsets from the file name
    latOffset := float64(50)
    lngOffset := float64(28)

    output, err := os.Create("N050E028_DSM.xyz")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    outputWriter := bufio.NewWriter(output)

    img, err := tiff.Decode(bufio.NewReader(input))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    bounds := img.Bounds()
    for y := bounds.Min.Y; y < bounds.Max.Y; y++ {
        for x := bounds.Min.X; x < bounds.Max.X; x++ {
            // Normalize X and Y to a 0 to 1 space based on the size of the image.
            // Add the offsets to get coordinates.
            lng := lngOffset + (float64(x) / float64(bounds.Max.X))
            lat := latOffset + (float64(y) / float64(bounds.Max.Y))

            height := img.At(x, y).(color.Gray16)

            outputWriter.WriteString(strconv.FormatFloat(lng, 'f', 16, 64))
            outputWriter.WriteString(" ")
            outputWriter.WriteString(strconv.FormatFloat(lat, 'f', 16, 64))
            outputWriter.WriteString(" ")
            outputWriter.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(int(height.Y)))
            outputWriter.WriteString("\n")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I could not get the information in this way

Comment: Can you upload a sample file somewhere so we can see what you are dealing with?, since we can't download it from the provided link. And some info on this .XYZ format, is it the same as the one described on the Wikipedia article? Or some other format(seems likely since you are talking about geo data not chemistry)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OiFy-vLq9CvVeqNg9VogmxSPOMcpcD1W/view - link to TIFF.

Link to XYZ file example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmz6c.png

Comment: I was able to get a working example, hope it helps

Comment: You saved my nervous system. Thank You